# Using Spring-boot with two way SSL connection - issue configuring trust-store

Tags: java, security, ssl, spring-boot, https

I am using Spring-Boot Version 1.3.3.RELEASE. I'm trying to have my key-store and trust-store configured through application.yaml to set up two way SSL authentication.

There are two internal servers, one (call it A) using REST API to POST to the other (call it B, that's what I'm trying to configure).

Received our private key and cert (B's), merged it to a PKCS12 format and set it as the key-store (mykeystore.p12). Also received the other end private key and cert (A's), imported the cert only into a JKS format and set it as a trust-store (mytruststore.jks).

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: mykeystore.p12
    key-store-password: mypass
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    client-auth: need
    trust-store: mytruststore.jks
    trust-store-password: mypass
    trust-store-type: JKS
```

I wanted to test the connection, so I created a PKCS12 format cert from A's key and cert as well, and imported that into the browsers.
First the browser notifies me that the connection is not secure:

> localhost:8443 uses an invalid security certificate. 
>   The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
>   The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. 
>   An additional root certificate may need to be imported. 
>   The certificate is only valid for **.somedomain* 
>   Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

But after accepting the risk, the client's cert validation fails (browser doesn't ask me which cert I want to use as client's cert):

> An error occurred during a connection to some.domain. SSL peer cannot
>   verify your certificate. Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_ALERT

After that I created a self-signed certificate and key for test purposes, followed the steps above and with the self-signed certificate, it works. The browser asked which certificate I want to use as the client's cert, after selecting the only one I created, the SSL handshake was successful.

Tried to use the same PKCS12 format cert as key-store and trust-store, to make sure that the config is OK, but, again, it only worked with the self-signed cert.

My best guess I'm using localhost and B's cert's CN is **.somedomain*. I created a *test.somedomain* entry in the hosts file and tried to use that to test B's cert, but the error still occurs.

Did I miss or misconfigured something, or how could I test if I correctly set up the two way SSL with the given certs?